# Idea for good insulating s'chach

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkah, schach

I live in a fairly cold climate (at least during Sukkos, especially this year) and so I am always looking for ways to reduce heat-loss in my Sukkah.  There are plenty of options for the walls, but the s'chach is more difficult.  In previous years, I have used wood wool (the long thin wood shavings that you typically find in gift baskets) on top of a nylon net suspended under the typical modern reed mat s'chach, but this is tedious to arrange and as far as I understand is not really ideal halachically as the s'chach should not be supported by something not kosher for s'chach.  It can also get a bit messy.

I'm looking for ideas for how I can have some kind of kosher s'chach which will act as a good insulator without being too thick (not more than a few centimetres), not too time consuming to arrange and not too expensive (I'm not looking to spend hundreds of British Pounds).  The sukkah is about 3x4 metres and I have a sloping frame as I pull a sheet of tarpaulin over the top to protect the sukkah from the rain.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: besides woods, what options do you have and what do you expect from a Kosher Succah??

Comment: You're a bit limited with schach as it has to be naturally grown material. Some other possible options -  I think one of the biggest cooling factors is wind. Thus, a fairly thick covering of leaves seem to keep out most of the wind and does a decent job at preserving heat. Other than that, you could install floor heaters in the succah, or use suspended heating fans / lamps from the ceiling. Beyond that, keep in mind, that if it is unbearably cold, you are probably exempt from sitting in the succah, anyway.

Comment: I recommend you contact Chabad in a cold area (like Edmonton). They'll have ideas.

Comment: @DanF I have 2 heaters - a 2kW fan heater and a 2.5kW oil filled radiator, but most of the heat is quickly lost.  I'm trying to keep things comfortable for guests primarily as we like to invite family and friends.

Comment: @AlBerko Wood can come in a number of different forms!

Comment: If you're not leaving gaps to see the stars any way, couldn't you line up 2x4s?

Comment: @wizzardmr42 What's your baseline that you're trying to improve upon? Generally the fewer gaps, the more heat will stay in. So a bamboo mat would be better than loose branches.

Comment: Why not add another layer or 2 or 3 of typical modern reed mat s'chach?

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether raw cotton is kosher for schach? I see no reason why it shouldn’t be - it grows from the ground, is currently detached, and is not fashioned into a completed usable item. If you were to use this for schach, you’d need to take care with a sukkah schlock, since rain would completely destroy the cotton.

Comment: @Loewian I think there is a machlokes in the mishna whether that's ok.  I don't think it is considered ideal anyway